# How to return a full word of every match instead of just the portion of a word that matched using match?

Tags: javascript, regex

When I run this code below, the result will be `["ai", "ai"]`. I am trying to create a function that will return `["airport", "airplane"]`. What would be the best way to go about this?

```
var gill = ['airplane', 'airport', 'apple', 'ball']

function auto(word, array) {
  var geo = array.join(" ")

  var snoop = new RegExp(word, "gi")

  var gip = geo.match(snoop)

  console.log(gip)
}

auto("ai", gill)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var snoop = new RegExp("\\b\\S*" + word + "\\S*", "gi");
```

seems to do the job. It uses word boundary checks (`\b`).

However there are better options in ECMAScript 5.1, e.g. by using `filter`:

```js
var gill = [
  "airplane",
  "airport",
  "apple",
  "ball"
];

function auto(array, word){
  return array.filter(function(a){
    return new RegExp(word, "gi").test(a);
  });
}

console.log(auto(gill, "ai"));
```

Comment: I think the \\S\\b at the end is overkill. I think since he joins on a space you can just do something like `'\\b'+word+'[^\\s]+'.  regardless ++ :)

Comment: @Rooster You’re right. I didn’t really think about the logic, it was just symmetrical and that’s why I’ve written it that way. I removed the second `\\b`.

Comment: If there are Unicode letters in the beginning, `\b` will not work, as it is not Unicode aware in JS regex.